# convert spaces to params in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0, invoke-command

$arglist = "/p:stuff=`"Release|x64`" /p:InstallerStuff=`"Release|x64`" /p:InstallerLanguages=`"en-US`""

$cmd = "./create.cmd"

invoke-expression $cmd $arglist

fails because there are spaces in arglist, how do i encode or escape the space so they are passed to the cmd script ?

Answer (score 0):

$args = $arglist.split(' ')
invoke-expression $cmd $args[0] $args[1] $args[2]